# Insert rows one by one postgresql

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, salesforce

I want to insert a parent row in table1 and set its external id and then i want to insert a child row in the same table1 using the external id set in the parent row in postgresql.

I'm getting an error in the child row that the external id does not exist.
Is there a way to solve this?

These are my queries:

```
INSERT INTO salesforce.opportunity (Name,recordtypeid,StageName,closedate,person_account__r__externalid__c,externalid__c)
VALUES ('testMBexternalId5', '0120Y000000R4WEQA0', 'Qualification','2019-08-01','0014E00000hyqW5','test105');

INSERT INTO salesforce.opportunity (Name,recordtypeid,StageName,closedate,master_booking_fk__r__externalid__c)
VALUES ('test booking script225', '0120Y000000R4WJQA0', 'Qualification','2019-08-01', 'test105');
```

This is the error:
`{"op": "INSERT", "src": "SFDC", "msg": "Foreign key external ID: test105 not found for field Externalid__c in entity Opportunity"}`.

This is the definition of the table:

```
-- Table: salesforce.opportunity

-- DROP TABLE salesforce.opportunity;

CREATE TABLE salesforce.opportunity
(
    first_status_fk__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    channel__c character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    person_account__c character varying(18) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    utm_campaign__c character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    channelcategory__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    booking_id__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    contact__c character varying(18) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    loss_reason__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    invoiced_amount__c double precision,
    channel_description__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    rate__c character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    phone_numberbooking__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    trip_reason__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    firstnamebooking__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    deposit__c double precision,
    pmsbookingid__c character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    master_booking_id__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    restart_date__c date,
    bookingupdatable__c boolean,
    closedate date,
    recordtypeid character varying(18) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    utm_term__c character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    pmsclientid__c character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    bookingerrorcode__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    accountid character varying(18) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    checkindate__c date,
    business_lead__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    source__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    stagename character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    phone_number__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    first_name__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    client_fk__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    max_departure__c date,
    option_date__c date,
    contact__r__externalid__c character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    bookingerrormessage__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    language__c character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    name character varying(120) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lastnamebooking__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    mobile_phone_number__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lastmodifieddate timestamp without time zone,
    trip_context__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    ownerid character varying(18) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    last_name__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    checkoutdate__c date,
    bookingsource__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    hotel__c character varying(18) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    isdeleted boolean,
    bookingcancellable__c boolean,
    systemmodstamp timestamp without time zone,
    account__externalid__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lastmodifiedbyid character varying(18) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    status__c character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    e_mail__c character varying(80) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    master_booking_fk__r__externalid__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    crsbookingid__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    error_message__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    probability double precision,
    creation_date__c date,
    createddate timestamp without time zone,
    current_status_fk__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    guarentee__c character varying(15) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    utm_source__c character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    bookerdevice__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    min_arrival__c date,
    prolongation__c date,
    amount double precision,
    cad_status__c character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    start_date__c date,
    bookingstatus__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nb_children__c double precision,
    createdbyid character varying(18) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    type character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    utm_content__c character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    opportunity_scope__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email_addressbooking__c character varying(80) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    master_booking_fk__c character varying(18) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    distributionmode__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    externalid__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    payment_at_booking__c boolean,
    bookingcomment__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lost_against__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    hotel_id__c character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    utm_medium__c character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    hotel__r__hotel_id__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    partner_code__c character varying(15) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nb_adults__c double precision,
    include_breakfast__c boolean,
    distribution__c character varying(34) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    error_code__c character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    sfid character varying(18) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('salesforce.opportunity_id_seq'::regclass),
    _hc_lastop character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    _hc_err text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    person_account__r__externalid__c character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    masterbookingexternalidbbus__c character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT opportunity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "OPP_EXTERNAL_ID" UNIQUE (externalid__c)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE salesforce.opportunity
    OWNER to u7kra5fpd0kfj2;

GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON TABLE salesforce.opportunity TO "TEST_USER";

GRANT ALL ON TABLE salesforce.opportunity TO u7kra5fpd0kfj2;

-- Index: hc_idx_opportunity_accountid

-- DROP INDEX salesforce.hc_idx_opportunity_accountid;

CREATE INDEX hc_idx_opportunity_accountid
    ON salesforce.opportunity USING btree
    (accountid COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: hc_idx_opportunity_contact__c

-- DROP INDEX salesforce.hc_idx_opportunity_contact__c;

CREATE INDEX hc_idx_opportunity_contact__c
    ON salesforce.opportunity USING btree
    (contact__c COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: hc_idx_opportunity_crsbookingid__c

-- DROP INDEX salesforce.hc_idx_opportunity_crsbookingid__c;

CREATE INDEX hc_idx_opportunity_crsbookingid__c
    ON salesforce.opportunity USING btree
    (crsbookingid__c COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: hc_idx_opportunity_hotel__c

-- DROP INDEX salesforce.hc_idx_opportunity_hotel__c;

CREATE INDEX hc_idx_opportunity_hotel__c
    ON salesforce.opportunity USING btree
    (hotel__c COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: hc_idx_opportunity_lastmodifieddate

-- DROP INDEX salesforce.hc_idx_opportunity_lastmodifieddate;

CREATE INDEX hc_idx_opportunity_lastmodifieddate
    ON salesforce.opportunity USING btree
    (lastmodifieddate)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: hc_idx_opportunity_master_booking_fk__c

-- DROP INDEX salesforce.hc_idx_opportunity_master_booking_fk__c;

CREATE INDEX hc_idx_opportunity_master_booking_fk__c
    ON salesforce.opportunity USING btree
    (master_booking_fk__c COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: hc_idx_opportunity_person_account__c

-- DROP INDEX salesforce.hc_idx_opportunity_person_account__c;

CREATE INDEX hc_idx_opportunity_person_account__c
    ON salesforce.opportunity USING btree
    (person_account__c COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: hc_idx_opportunity_systemmodstamp

-- DROP INDEX salesforce.hc_idx_opportunity_systemmodstamp;

CREATE INDEX hc_idx_opportunity_systemmodstamp
    ON salesforce.opportunity USING btree
    (systemmodstamp)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: hcu_idx_opportunity_externalid__c

-- DROP INDEX salesforce.hcu_idx_opportunity_externalid__c;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hcu_idx_opportunity_externalid__c
    ON salesforce.opportunity USING btree
    (externalid__c COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: hcu_idx_opportunity_sfid

-- DROP INDEX salesforce.hcu_idx_opportunity_sfid;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hcu_idx_opportunity_sfid
    ON salesforce.opportunity USING btree
    (sfid COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Trigger: BeforeInsertOpportunity

-- DROP TRIGGER "BeforeInsertOpportunity" ON salesforce.opportunity;

CREATE TRIGGER "BeforeInsertOpportunity"
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON salesforce.opportunity
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE salesforce."SetExternalId"();

-- Trigger: hc_opportunity_logtrigger

-- DROP TRIGGER hc_opportunity_logtrigger ON salesforce.opportunity;

CREATE TRIGGER hc_opportunity_logtrigger
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON salesforce.opportunity
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (((get_xmlbinary())::text = 'base64'::text))
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE salesforce.hc_opportunity_logger();

-- Trigger: hc_opportunity_status_trigger

-- DROP TRIGGER hc_opportunity_status_trigger ON salesforce.opportunity;

CREATE TRIGGER hc_opportunity_status_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON salesforce.opportunity
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE salesforce.hc_opportunity_status();
```

Can I insert the row parent and then the row child or there is another solution?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the definition of the table and its keys.

Comment: Can you commit in between your inserts?

Comment: @indiri i tried to commit in between it doesn't work. I dont know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: the table has a column named externalid__c that is used as constraint key. I fill this column in the first insert. In the second insert and in order to attach the child to the parent i should fill the column master_booking__externalid__c with the external id of the first row. Now if i put each insert alone in pgadmin it works, but if i put them together it doesn't work.

Comment: Rather than describing it in words, could you edit the question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements including constraints?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The table is a table automatically created in salesforce app. I don't create it. I only insert or update rows in it via pgAdmin and it's synchronized via "Heroku connect" into salesforce app. And i have specified in pgAdmin that the externalid__c column is a constraint Key.

Comment: But you can use `pg_dump -s` to get the table definition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Excuse me but i am new to postgresql i don't know how to use it. i tried this command: pg_dump -s 'salesforce.opportunity' but doesn't work. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Try `pg_dump -s -t 'salesforce.opportunity' <name of your database>`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe This is the definition of the table:

Comment: You should edit the question and add it there.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have edited the question

Comment: The foreign keys would also be helpful. You can get them from `\d salesforce.opportunity` in psql.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The foreign Keys are mentioned in the definition of the table as Contraint key: CONSTRAINT opportunity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "OPP_EXTERNAL_ID" UNIQUE (externalid__c).

Comment: From where to where does the foreign key point? The error message you are getting is not from PostgreSQL, right?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I Know that the error I am getting is because postgres are inserting the two rows in bulk and in the same table (the externalId of the first row is not yet entered in the table and i am using it in the second row). If I can do a method to insert the row seperatly, I think that I will not get the error anymore.

Comment: That should not matter - they are not inserted in the same SQL statement. But if you have a workaround, that's cool.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe In fact, if i do the same insert but each one in a different transaction, it works but i really need them in the same transaction. Is there a solution or not?

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense to me. It actually looks like this error message is from Salesforce or at least from something other than PostgreSQL. Then the problem would have to be solved on that level. Can you look into the PostgreSQL server log if there is an error message about a foreign key violation?